# How to parse string with format Culture and UI Culture (c=nb-NO|uic=nb-NO) to language code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to ask how to parse string with format Culture and UI Culture (c=nb-NO|uic=nb-NO) to language code nb-No using service of C# or .net
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Comment: Regular expression?

Comment: It can but better if I have a method to solve that. :D Thanks Klaus Gütter

Comment: Please show some code example of the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using a regex:

```
var input = "(c=nb-NO|uic=nb-NO)";
var cultureName = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\(c=)[^|]+").Value;
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=\(c=)` looks for "(c=" in the input string (as an anchor, but not included in the match)
- `[^|]+` matches every character which is not a "|"

Depending on what the exact specification of possible input values is, this might have to be adapted a bit.

Comment: Thanks Klaus Gütter. Look like dont have any method support my request. So I will appcept your answer. And could you help to provide a regex for "c=nb-NO|uic=nb-NO". :D This is string I got in my app. Many thanks.

Comment: After this question, I will research how regex working.

Comment: Maybe I found the regex. `(?<=c=)[^|]+`